# How to set width of combined fields in Python logging

Tags: python, logging, formatting

In Python logging, is there a way to set the width of two combined fields?

I'm looking to combine filenames and line numbers to produce output similar to:

```
2011-10-14 13:47:51 main.py:12       DEBUG - Initializing cluster
2011-10-14 13:47:51 cluster.py:364   DEBUG - Starting cluster
2011-10-14 13:47:51 cluster.py:98    INFO  - Starting simulation
2011-10-14 13:47:51 simulation.py:79 DEBUG - Computing parameters
```

How would I modify the formatting string below, to achieve this?

```
logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s %(levelname)5s - %(msg)s
```

---

**UPDATE:**

As @jonrsharpe points out, no out-of-the-box way to do this, so have customize the formatting.

Solution: @alecxe recommends a custom `Filter`, and here is a complete example:

```
import logging
import logging.config

class FilenameLinenoFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.filename_lineno = '{}:{}'.format(record.filename, record.lineno)
        return True

LOG_SETTINGS = {
    'version': 1,
    'filters': {
        'filename_lineno_filter': {
            '()': FilenameLinenoFilter,
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(filename_lineno)-18s %(levelname)5s - %(msg)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['filename_lineno_filter'],
            'formatter': 'standard',
            },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': { 
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOG_SETTINGS)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.debug('Debug output goes here.')
logger.info('Informational goes here.')
```

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to do that, unless you take over all of the formatting yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a *combined field* with the help of a [*custom filter*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17558764/771848):

```
import logging

class MyFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.filename_lineno = "%s:%d" % (record.filename, record.lineno)
        return True
```

Then, you can reference the `%(filename_lineno)s` placeholder in the formatting string.

Answer (score 6):

A `Filter` is not the right tool for the job—filters are used to decide which log records get emitted and which are silenced, not to intercept log records just to "monkeypatch" them.

Rather, as of Python 3.2, you can use the [`logging.setRecordFactory`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html#logging.setLogRecordFactory) function to register a custom [`LogRecord`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord) subclass or factory function to add a custom attribute to every `LogRecord`:

```py
import logging

class CustomLogRecord(logging.LogRecord):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.origin = f"{self.filename}:{self.lineno}"
```

You can then set the width of this combined field in the format string for your logger:

```py
logging.setLogRecordFactory(CustomLogRecord)
logging.basicConfig(
    style='{',
    format="{asctime} {origin:20} {levelname} - {message}",
    level=logging.INFO
)
logging.info("Test")
```

```
2020-06-26 16:10:03,193 scratch_2.py:16      INFO - Test
```

Comment: The logging cookbook has a similar example that might be of interest
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#customizing-logrecord