# How can I rename "levelname" to "level" in Python log messages?

Tags: python, logging

I have a Python logging configuration which looks like this:

```
LOGGING_CONFIG:
    version: 1
    formatters:
        human:
            class: logging.Formatter
            format: '[%(asctime)s]:[%(levelname)s]: %(message)s'
        json:
            class: pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter
            format: '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'
    handlers:
        console:
            class: logging.StreamHandler
            level: DEBUG
            formatter: json  # change this to 'human' when you run it locally, json in production
        file:
            class: logging.FileHandler
            filename: logfile.log
            level: DEBUG
            formatter: json
    root:  # Logging for 3rd party stuff
        level: INFO
        handlers:
            - console
            - file
    project_name:  # Logging this module
        level: DEBUG
        handlers:
            - console
            - file
```

For another system, I need the structured logging to have some fixed names. One example is that it should not be `levelname`, but `level`. How can I rename log fields?

What I have:

```
{"asctime": "2018-10-22 14:50:19,923", "levelname": "info", "message": "foobar"}
```

What I want:

```
{"asctime": "2018-10-22 14:50:19,923", "level": "info", "message": "foobar"}
```

Comment: Yes, I see `levelname` in the output. I would like to see `level` instead.

Comment: It might be possible with [LoggerAdapter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#loggeradapter-objects)

Answer (score 11):

`levelname` will not appear in normal Python loggers but in the custom formatter you used. From what I understood you could use below snippet to customize the dict it outputs:

```
class CustomJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter):
    def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
        super(CustomJsonFormatter, self).add_fields(log_record, record, message_dict)
        log_record['level'] = log_record['levelname']
        del log_record['levelname']
```

Then replace `pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter` with the address of `CustomJsonFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with this following configuration:

```
...
formatters:
  json:
    format: "%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s"
    (): pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter
    rename_fields:
      levelname: level
    timestamp: true
```

...

Comment: This worked.  Be sure to use `(): ...` instead of `class: ...` in the YAML (as it is in the above snippet).