# How to distinguish between files and submodules in Python logging?

Tags: python, logging, python-module

I wrote a submodule where I define logging there since I mainly use my submodule to reuse code in my different rest api projects. How can I set up my custom logging record so that logging knows which code (`main.py` or `sub.py`) called the logging? I tried using `__file__`, but then it would always say "sub.py".

My submodule:

```
# sub.py
import logging
from secrets import token_urlsafe

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/57820456/1150923
def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):
    record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
    record.session_id = session_id

    # What do I do here?
    # This doesn't work:
    record.src = __file__

    return record

session_id = token_urlsafe(8)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
old_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()
logging.setLogRecordFactory(record_factory)

# Always prepend session_id and src to logs
format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(session_id) %(src) %(message)s", datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(format)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info("Hello!") # Should also print out "sub.py".
```

My main script:

```
# main.py
import logging
import sub

logger = logging.getLogger("sub")
logger.info("Hi!") # Should also print out "main.py".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging provides an attribute for the module name, the same value as `__file__`, under the name `pathname`.

Replace `%(src)s` with `%(pathname)s`.

The way the `Logger` does it is via stack inspection in the `Logger.findCaller` method. It walks up the stack until it finds a frame that isn't in the logging module. And then extracts that frame's filename, lineno, and function name.

See [Is module __file__ attribute absolute or relative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116889/is-module-file-attribute-absolute-or-relative) for the issue with `__name__`.

Comment: Any idea why it only says `./main.py` for the main file, but the full path like `/Users/hobbes3/sub.py` for the submodule? Ideally, I would like it to say the full path for both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **inspect** module in this case.

```
import inspect as insp

def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):
    record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
    record.session_id = session_id

    (filename, line_number,func_name, lines, index) = insp.getframeinfo(insp.currentframe().f_back)

    #Do whatever with this values.
    return record
```

The way `currentframe()` works is it returns the frame object for the caller’s stack frame. This can be passed into the getframeinfo() method.

Find more details here : [inspect Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)